# Convert to a fraction form

Tags: calculus

I found the following problem in our problembook and I am clueless how to start

> Transform to a fraction form:
>
> $3.\overline{123}$

This is the first time I am trying to solve such a problem and I don't know how to start.

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $x$ be the number you want to find in fraction form. Then look at $1000 x - x$.

Answer (score 0):

However many digits have the bar,
just divide it by that many 9's.

So
$3.\overline{123}
=3\dfrac{123}{999}
=3\dfrac{41}{333}
$.

Answer (score 0):

That decimal part is a pain because it goes on forever.

But because it repeats, we can subtract it out by multiplying by some power of $10$.

Let

$$x = 3.\overline{123}$$

Then

$$1000x = 3123.\overline{123}$$

Subtract the two, witness the magic, and solve for $x$.